# C# string manipulation with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a way to insert a string into another string using regex.

For example, if I have a %-separated string of the following format:

%PartOneOfString%PartTwoOfString%PartThreeOfString%

Is there a way using regex to append a suffix to ONLY the first part of the string, so that the result is:

%PartOneOfString_suffix%PartTwoOfString%PartThreeOfString%

Thanks!
Charlie

Comment: Have you tried anything? Since without regex, simple strings operations seem to enough to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^%([^%]*)?%");
var s = regex.Replace("%PartOneOfString%PartTwoOfString%PartThreeOfString%", @"%$1_Suffix%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with simple `String.Replace Method (String, String)` method as detailed in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Regards,